# how to update date type in a table?

Tags: plsql

If you have two tables, table1 and table2, and
both tables have a date column, 
how to update a column in table1 by checking the date in table2?
If there is no table2 performed in the last 365 days.
Using a PL/SQL block to do the same.

Comment: "If there is no table2 performed in the last 365 days." is an incomplete sentence. "Using a PL/SQL block to do the same." The same as what? Please update your question further and make  clear what you are asking. Include the code that you have, table examples and where things go wrong. (Don't "answer" with a comment, just edit your post).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look about the functions of Triggers: [Link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/) 
I think you need a `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` Trigger.